# How to set up cloudboost in android app with my own server?

Tags: java, android, cloudboost

I am new in cloud boost.

I am using cloud boost in my android application for chat feature.

We have integrated cloud boost SDK on our server.

Now I want to use cloud boost in my android app with my server URL but I am not able to init CloupApp with custom URL. I have also tried following method but it not work.

```
CloudSocket.init(cloudUrl);
CloudApp.init(appId, appKey);
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library does not support Java/Android and other languages - it only supports Javascript language.

Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/CloudBoost/JavaSDK/issues/9

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)